# I would like to change the background color in the Kendo Scheduler

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler

I am using a Kendo MVC Scheduler control and it looks like this:

[image]

You can see all the background colors are blue. I would like to change this default to a different color. I cannot find a way to do this. I thought maybe this styling would work in my view, but it doesn't:

```
<style>
    .k-event {
        background: red;
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

This is how I have the Scheduler defined:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<LaibeManpower.Entities.OnCallSchedule>()
        .Name("OnCallSchedule")
        .Date(new DateTime(System.DateTime.Now.Ticks))
        .Height(800)
        .Editable(false)
        .Pdf(pdf => pdf
            .FileName("OnCall Schedule.pdf")
            .ProxyURL(Url.Action("PdfExportSave", "OnCallSchedule"))
        )
        .Toolbar(t => t.Pdf())
        .Views(views =>
        {
            views.WeekView();
            views.DayView();
        })
        .Selectable(true)
        .DataSource(d => d
            .Model(m => {
                m.Id(f => f.RowId);
            })
            .ServerOperation(true)
            .Read(read => read.Action("ReadSchedule", "OnCall").Data("getAdditionalData"))
        )
```

Comment: If you're not suing resources, your CSS code should work. Check in your browser's developer tools if it's loaded and whether another rule overrides it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I had to do was to put the following in a separate .CSS file and load it. Then it worked.

```
.k-event {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

Comment: 1. The rule `background: red` is incorrect and redundant, so remove it from your answer. 
2. What probably made it work is a different [source order in the CSS cascade](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance#Understanding_the_cascade) . To make this a valuable StackOverflow answer, address the root cause of your problem.